# Im learning socket , but cant resolve the error in my client File

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

client.py

```
while True:
        full_msg= ""
        new_msg = True
        while True:
                msg = c.recv(15)
                if new_msg :
                        msglen = int(msg[:headersize])
                        new_msg = False   
                full_msg += msg.decode("utf-8")
                if len(full_msg)-headersize == msglen:
                                print("full msg recvd, Length = ", msglen)
                                print(full_msg[headersize:])
                                new_msg = True
```

This shows error as :
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b''

Comment: What is the output of `print(msg[:headersize])`?

Comment: In the last iteration:  b''.

Comment: What is ``msg``? What is ``headersize``? What do you do with the *rest* of ``msg`` from which you only read ``headersize``?

Comment: this is a code extract, headersize = 10 is defined above, header is added to message in the server file, in the client file header is extracted and message is printed

Answer (score 0):

The error apparently occurs in this line (the only one callint `int()`:

```
msglen = int(msg[:headersize])
```

If you inspect `msg` you'll see it is a `bytes` object, not a string. You need to use `.decode` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
msglen = int(msg[:headersize])
```

try:

```
msglen = int(msg[:headersize].decode('utf-8'))
```